# Dynamically Pivot unknown Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

Trying to pivot **dynamic** data using LINQ or LAMBDA in C#/MVC4 and have pretty much come to the conclusion that its very difficult to do..

This is basically what I want to do:
[image: Pivot]

I have been able to get this to work with known column names using this example: http://geekswithblogs.net/malisancube/archive/2009/04/21/using-lambda-or-linq-for-pivot-tables.aspx

But I cant find any examples for doing this with dynamic columns.

By dynamic columns I mean that there could be a new row with a different Name and FieldType that has not been in the table before at any time that also needs to be turned into a column.. any pointers?.

Comment: I'm also wondering If I can create a SQL Function that sorts this out for me.. But I haven't found a nice way of using SQL Functions from MVC4 yet.. ie. I'm fine with writing the function by hand but I would prefer to use some MVC-ish method of calling the function.

Comment: Does this have to be done in `linq`?  This could easily be done with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: I would prefer to do this in LINQ, but if no other options exist I'm open to any "good" solution that is efficient and fast.

Comment: What RDBMS?  Sql server, oracle, mysql? and what version?

Comment: Ended up using this: http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot

Comment: I am glad you figured out a way to get this done. Like I said, I didn't know Linq so I gave a different way to get the result. :)

Comment: I tried using the method you provided, problem is you cant use the query with EntityFramework as it does not allow you to use T-SQL that returns an unknown number of columns. I would then instead have to establish a separate connection every time I want to use this query and that does not seem like the most performance effective way to do this.

Comment: I totally understand that I am glad you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `LINQ` so I will give you a version that can be used in a SQL Server stored procedure.  This type of data transformation is known as a `PIVOT`.  Since you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use the function.

If you know the values that you want to transform, then you can hard-code the values:

```
SELECT nodeid, rowid,[FirstName], [LastName], [Title]
FROM
(
    SELECT nodeid, rowid, name, value
    FROM yourTable
) x
PIVOT
(
   max(value)
   for name in ([FirstName], [LastName], [Title])
)p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aff45/1)

Then if you have an unknown number of values, you can implement dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT nodeid, rowid,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT nodeid, rowid, name, value
                FROM yourTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cf07/1)

Both return the results:

```
| NODEID | ROWID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |  TITLE |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1 |     1 |    Alfred |   Beagle | (null) |
|      1 |     2 |    Freddy |   (null) | (null) |
|      1 |     3 |    (null) |     Grey |   Sir. |
```

Comment: Great answer, will test when I get home. Wondering if theres anything in particular I need to think about concerning sql injections.. The value and name column can basically contain ANYTHING.

Comment: Got this to work as you described it, trying to see if I can fine tune it down to one single select statement ;)

Comment: @JensBerfenfeldt glad you got it working. You probably can, I split it out for clarity. :)

Comment: Not sure how though, think I might have to settle for 2 queries.